# Reason to discourage use of back or refresh button on net banking sites

Tags: session, https

I just want to know why refresh/back button is not recommended while using netbanking sites?
Is it because of session object that might get invalidated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your average banking site contains forms. To protect the user from accidentially performing some action by eg. clicking a link (or, more general, by some sort of request forgery), the forms can have an additional hidden field containing some random value.

That random value is also stored on the server side and used to check whether the form can contain parameters for a valid action (ie. the form token must match the server token).

The disadvantage is that, if you use the browser controls, you get back to the previous page, but probably without the server noticing. Thus, you use an old form token, the result being that the server will refuse to perform the specified action, because the form token does not match the server-side information.

As a side effect, this incident may lead to the currently active session to be terminated for security reasons.